# Spring form commandName = session attribute

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have many pages with the same form where I bind my object using commandName. I try to put the object to session with name "myObject" and use it for form (commandName = "myObject"). But system throws exception (Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name "myObject"). 
How can I bind the object to session for any controllers and requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error is typical when your use a `form:form` tag that targets a command object that is not available in the request.

A good approach is to combine `@ModelAttribute` annotated method with `@SessionAttributes` on a Controller that intially forwards to the view that contains the form, something like

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("myObject")
public class FormController {

    @ModelAttribute("myObject")
    public MyObject createMyObjectBean() {
        return new MyObject();
    }
    ...
}
```

The initally `createMyObjectBean` will be called with whatever is the first request to the controller methods, but it won't be called on subsequent request as the `myObject` value will come from session due to `@SessionAttributes`

just note that for this approach to work, you must have a controller that forwards to the view that contains your form

Comment: It's works only when my requests are resolved with methods in Controller with @SessionAttributes annotation but when request is resolved with other controllers i have the same issue. How can I put my object for all request in all controllers?

Comment: You can use the exemplary controller as a parent, and let all of the other controllers extend from it

Comment: Thanks for replay but in my case I decided to put the object in a session and use jstl for rendering into jsp. for getting from request I use ModelAttribute. I think it's more simple way.

Comment: Or you can use ControllerAdvice if you don't want to use inheritance